# consuming json with digit variable names in typescript

Tags: json, typescript, deserialization, swagger

I'm consuming the JSON from swagger, and when I get to the responses I get a bunch of variables that are the response codes, aka numbers. The relevant section of the JSON is below.

```
"responses": {
  "200": {
    "description": "OK"
  },
  "404": {
    "description": "not found"
  },
  "503": {
    "description": "Problem with external dependency"
  }
}
```

How do I deserialize this into a Typescript object or should I use a service to consume this and process it before handing something more manageable to Typescript? My current idea is to handle it in javascript, then spit something back that is easier to consume in typescript; but before diving down that rabbit hole (ok, not quite that bad, I can see the bottom) I figured that I'd see if there is a better solution.

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/L8dpomL8/

Comment: This example includes two different approaches, one where the property names are static, the other where they aren't. https://jsfiddle.net/L8dpomL8/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript only exists at compile-time. At run-time everything is plain old JavaScript.

As (de)serialization happens at run-time you would be deserializing it in to a JavaScript object, but I assume you mean "Is it possible to create a TypeScript type definition that describes this incoming object?".

Also, the property names aren't numbers, they're strings that happen to contain numbers. This is an important distinction when creating a type definition as a string and a number are two different types.

The first step is to define the Response objects:

```
interface IResponse {
  description: string;
}
```

Then, there are two approaches that can be taken for defining the Responses object. The first can be used if the property names are known in advance, the second can be used in a more generic fashion to support any property names of a given type.

### Known Names

```
interface IKnownResponses {
  "200": IResponse;
  "300"?: IResponse;
  "400": IResponse;
}
```

This defines an interface that must have properties called "200" and "400", and can optionally have a property called "300".

"300" is [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) (search for the "Optional Properties" title) as it's property definition has a ? in it.

### Dynamic Names

```
interface IDynamicResponses {
    [responseCode: string]: IResponse;
}
```

This interface says that any string can be used as a key/property name, but that the property must contain an `IResponse`.

This is an [indexer definition](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) (look for the section titled "Indexable Types").

### Example

These approaches can be seen working in the following example code:

```
interface IResponse {
  description: string;
}

interface IKnownResponses {
  "200": IResponse;
  "300"?: IResponse;
  "400": IResponse;
}

interface IDynamicResponses {
    [responseCode: string]: IResponse;
}

let knownResponses: IKnownResponses = {
    "200": {
    description: "foo"
  },
  "400": {
    description: "bar"
  }
};

let dynamicResponses: IDynamicResponses = {
    "200": {
    description: "foo"
  },
  "400": {
    description: "bar"
  },
  "401": {
    description: "baz"
  }
};

console.log(staticResponses["200"].description);
console.log(knownResponses["401"].description);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L8dpomL8/3/

Unfortunately JSFiddle isn't a very good TypeScript IDE so it's hard to show the type information being used, but if you take this code and put it in your preferred IDE you should be able to experiment with it and figure out where the typings help you, and where they fail.